# Как работать с удалённой базой данных на C# Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

У меня есть база данных, которая находится на другом компьютере в моей локальной сети. Как можно удалённо получить доступ к базе данных?

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ. Добавьте в него как можно больше деталей. И укажите, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Entity Framework без разницы, удаленная у вас БД или нет. Настройка доступа - это вопрос к вашей конкретной БД и к вашей настройке сети.